# How to get welcome text in template(Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configuration

How I can get fetch the welcome text of **Configuration** in Template file.

For e.g. **welcome text** : "Free shipping above $3"

It is located under **System/Configuration/design/header**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code in your template file :

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome') ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in Magento2 :(

Answer (score 2):

you can get with  below code

reference location **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php** check method **getWelcome()** line **95**

```
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
```